# ActionScript 3 Read JPEG quality

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, jpeg

I am developing image uploader for Flash 10. Is there a way to read jpeg quality of the browsed images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can't be done directly:

> The quality factor is not stored
>   directly in the JPEG file, so you
>   cannot read the quality factor from
>   the file. *(from: [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B324790&x=16&y=6#) pages...)*

In more detail:

> The quantization table that was used
>   to compress an image is stored in
>   the JFIF header, but the JPEG Quality
>   Factor that was used to generate the
>   quantization table is not stored along
>   with the image and hence the original
>   JPEG Quality Factor is lost. *(from: [JPEG Compression Metrics as a Quality Aware Image Transcoding](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:j2Zk2KXznzMJ:www.usenix.org/events/usits99/full_papers/chandra/chandra.pdf+%22IJG+scale%22+header&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiUaSRAI0kIXpVSTWnBe37rAgsRzeyaVBihrP3xGzkqbs6IobNkaD104eNCfGN4cdW_revy0CvL_O3SHgXDpUfMY1cyReiOLGWxHRGgvrR8rVwJ2EHEbHkSHXyv1SjZPdBPOv87&sig=AHIEtbTxfAFq9GM5Kq9YLDWeprs6OV-xTA), by Surendar Chandra and Carla Schlatter Ellis)*

The above quote is from a paper which discusses ways to **estimate the level of compression** (by examining the quantization tables used in the image), but it doesn't look easy to implement: there's an example [here](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/coders/jpeg.c#L683) which is part of the [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org) codebase, but it's written in C.

Image Magick has been [ported](http://code.google.com/p/nmagick/) to [Haxe](http://haxe.org/doc/targets/flash), which can be complied into Flash code, so conceivably you could get something working, but I'm afraid it's beyond my skills to explain how!

---

EDIT: just found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/62730/how-to-find-the-jpg-quality) on SuperUser, which also mentions Image Magick.

---

EDIT: you might also be interested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252693/get-dimension-of-locally-loaded-large-image), which asked how to get the size of an image without loading the whole file (good for dealing with images bigger than Flash can handle).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the libjpeg to finish this job, maybe you can refer to my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "jpeglib.h"
#include <setjmp.h>

static const unsigned int std_luminance_quant_tbl[DCTSIZE2] = {
  16,  11,  10,  16,  24,  40,  51,  61,
  12,  12,  14,  19,  26,  58,  60,  55,
  14,  13,  16,  24,  40,  57,  69,  56,
  14,  17,  22,  29,  51,  87,  80,  62,
  18,  22,  37,  56,  68, 109, 103,  77,
  24,  35,  55,  64,  81, 104, 113,  92,
  49,  64,  78,  87, 103, 121, 120, 101,
  72,  92,  95,  98, 112, 100, 103,  99
};

int ReadJpegQuality(const char *filename)
{
  FILE * infile = fopen(filename, "rb");
  fseek(infile,0,SEEK_END);
  size_t sz = ftell(infile);
  fseek(infile,0,SEEK_SET);
  unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[sz];
  fread(buffer,1,sz,infile);
  fclose(infile);
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
  jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo,(unsigned char*)buffer,sz);
  jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
  int tmp_quality = 0;
  int linear_quality = 0;
  const int aver_times = 3;
  int times = 0;
  int aver_quality = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<DCTSIZE2;i++)
  {
    long temp = cinfo.quant_tbl_ptrs[0]->quantval[i];
    if(temp<32767L&&temp>0)
    {
      linear_quality = ceil((float)(temp*100L - 50L)/std_luminance_quant_tbl[i]);
      if(linear_quality==1) tmp_quality = 1;
      else if(linear_quality==100) tmp_quality = 100;
      else if(linear_quality>100)
      {
        tmp_quality = ceil((float)5000/linear_quality);
      }
      else
      {
        tmp_quality = 100 - ceil((float)linear_quality/2);
      }
      aver_quality += tmp_quality;
      if(aver_times==++times)
      {
        aver_quality /= aver_times;
        break;
      } 
    }
  }
  jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
  return aver_quality;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  printf("quality: %d\n",ReadJpegQuality("test1.jpg"));
  return 0; 
}
```

this method is using the libjpeg to read jpg file's quantization table,then use the quantization table calculate the quality arguments.