# How to programmatically distinguish the professional photo from the amateur photo?

Tags: image, machine-learning, photo, deep-learning

What are the different options and solutions (software) that will help  distinguish professional (good) from amateur (bad) photo?

The criteria can be the contrast, sharpness, noise, presence of compression artifacts, etc. The question is, what are the tools that allow all this to determine it (the machine, not the man). For all of these criteria can be represented as mathematical models, you think?

Or in other words - to "feed" tool 1000 high-quality photos and 1000 substandard. And machine itself has identified the factors that distinguish the good from the bad image.

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29970747/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite vague definition of a problem. The only thing you have is 1000 high-quality photos and 1000 substandard photos. Your application however, is quite concrete, and I doubt (but I'm not sure) that you will find such a software.

Without looking to your images and have some tests is also difficult to say if contrast/gamma would be enough to classify them properly.

What you can do, if you know a bit of coding in matlab/python/C, is to use some existing libraries to try to solve your problem. I can't help you with that, as this itself is a quite tedious work, but, I can give you some insights.

To define your problem you will need:

- Input: 1000 pro images, 1000 std images

  You can represent this as 2000 images and a 2000 binary vector (1 for pro, 0 for std)
- Features

  Images itself might not give you enough information. What you can do is extract features from images. This step is called *feature extraction* and is an open research field in Computer Vision. There several feature extractors out there, you can try a couple of the most used ones, such as HoG or SIFT (have a look [here for examples](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/tut.html)).

  This feature extractors will give you a `1xM` numerical vector for each image. With `N` images, you have a `NxM` matrix composed of `N` images and their descriptor.
- Classification:

  Once you managed to extract features from the image, having `X = NxM data` and `y = label binary vector`, you can use any machine learning algorithm, such as Deep Neural Networks, Random Forests, Supported Vector Machines, or any other one, to train your data, and classify it later.

By putting everything together, you might be able to get decent results.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: @user2067861 Your welcome! let me know if you need further directions in any of those topics. In general this could be defined as a mix of Computer Vision (extracting information from images) and Machine Learning (classification/prediction of data). By googling how to extract features you can find very different solutions.

Comment: Earlier, we collected 150 good images and 150 bad images (in our opinion) and "fed" them a script written by Imagemagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php). And found the arithmetic mean of the values that gave the script. Different appeared the following values: kurtosis and skewness
Should I take them as a basis for determining the quality of the image?

Comment: @user2067861 From that script, it gives you quite information about the image, overall and channel-dependent *gamma*, *kurtosis*, *skewness*, *standard deviation*, *entropy*... I guess the mean color might not be important, but if you can flatten the aboves into a *feature vector* for each image, and feed them to a machine learning algorithm, you could (might) get some interesting results.

Comment: @user2067861 if you can get a .CVS file or something like that, with all those values for each image in rows (one row per image), and append 0 or 1 for proffesional or standard image (to each row). Then you can use something like [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) to try to classify it without needing to code anything. It has a nice user interface and you can feed it a .CVS file and apply classification over the data with a couple of clicks.

Comment: @user2067861 I didn't know about it, but I've used Theano (they use it) and it generally accepts images as an input and automaticaly extract features from them. What kind of input do they accept?

Answer (score 1):

Is this professional vs amateur photographer or equipment classification? I mean like distinguishing between a DLSR photo or a cell phone photo. Or is this distinguishing between an amateur with a DLSR and a professional with the same equipment? Or, are we talking about photoshop editing at the end.

In the case of equipment, I think features to look at would be noise, contrast, color gamut. In the case of skill of the photographer, you will probably have to look at features based on edge representations, natural scene metrics etc.

But, you will need to create a data matrix and then run a machine learning classification algorithm on it and hopefully find some features.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making or looking for art for humans or for robots?
The definition of a great photo is subjective by definition. What to one person may be junk to another is genius. Trying to take that and turn it into an equation is asking for AI to take over humankind.

I don't mean to be harsh in my assessment. My degree is in Fine Art, Painting. I put a lot of time and effort into thinking about images. It's a wonder to me how a child might make an image that seemed to be thoughtless but was a breakthrough in my perception. Conversely you can work for hours, day, months or even years and then feel like the result just doesn't measure up.

Photography is an ingenious invention, therefore all photography is a source for amazement.

I do agree with you however. Some photos are truly impressive. I think that if we approach this as coders than what we are seeking is 'likes' or 'page views' or some other method of getting counts from many people. I know that is not the answer you were looking for but I don't think you can find a better one. I wish you well on your quest.

If you want to judge a photo on technicalities then the edge of the physics should be your target. Currently that would be mirrorless cameras and 3d imaging.